# Lambda layer interfereing with indexing in graph - how to fix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running into an issue with a custom layer. My base example is this:

```
fd = np.random.rand(100,6)
fl = np.random.randint(0,1,[100,])

def get_m():
    I = Input(shape=(None, 6))
    d1 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='tanh')(I)
    d2 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='tanh')(d1)
    d3 = Dense(8, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='tanh')(d2)
    d4 = Dense(2, kernel_regularizer='l2', activation='relu')(d3)
    c = Concatenate()([d4, I])
    # this line
    hl = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.exp( -x[:, 4]/(1e-9 + x[:, 0]) - x[:, 5] / (1e-9 + x[:,1])))(c)
    return Model(inputs=I, outputs=hl)

model = get_m()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryFocalCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
model.fit(x=fd, y=fl, epochs=250, validation_split=0.1, class_weight={0: 852, 1: 749})
```

If I use the `class_weight` I get a 'could not squeeze' error after the first epoch:

```
Node: 'binary_focal_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze'
Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32
         [[{{node binary_focal_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_682739]
```

but if I don't use it, it trains. On the other hand, if I replace the lines after 'this
line' with

```
    d5 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(c)
    return Model(inputs=I, outputs=d5)
```

it also works.

What am I doing wrong and could I replace the line at `this line` with a non-layer transformation of `d4` and `I`?

Answer (score 1):

try and modify the Lambda layer to specify the output shape and here's the modified part of your code:

```
hl = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.exp(-x[:, 4] / (1e-9 + x[:, 0]) - x[:, 5] / (1e-9 + x[:, 1]), shape=(1,)))(c)
```

you should be able to use the Lambda layer in your model while applying class weights successfully.

Comment: This doesn't work? The argument is `output_shape` and the given value still gives an error